# How can I handle audio files?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, storage

What is the best option to:

1. Record audio from microphone,
2. Store the audio as files in memory,
3. Being able to play those files ?

Is there one package that is convenient to record and play? Does it works on all platforms (web compatible)? What is the best strategy to store them in memory?

Comment: there are a lot of it, try to find it out at https://pub.dev/packages?q=audio+

Answer (score 2):

Here is a package you can use [audio_recorder](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_recorder)

- For record and storing part here is sample examples (read the package documentation)

  ```
   // Import package
   import 'package:audio_recorder/audio_recorder.dart';

   // Check permissions before starting
   bool hasPermissions = await AudioRecorder.hasPermissions;

   // Get the state of the recorder
   bool isRecording = await AudioRecorder.isRecording;

   // Start recording
   await AudioRecorder.start(path: _controller.text, audioOutputFormat: AudioOutputFormat.AAC);

   // Stop recording
   Recording recording = await AudioRecorder.stop();
   print("Path : ${recording.path},  Format : ${recording.audioOutputFormat},  Duration : ${recording.duration},  Extension : ${recording.extension},");
  ```
- play audio you need another package i suggest [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) :

  ```
  // To pause 
  int result = await audioPlayer.pause();

  //To Stop 
  int result = await audioPlayer.stop();

  // To Jump through
  int result = await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: 1200));

  // To Resume 
  int result = await audioPlayer.resume();
  ```